# getting integer out of a ndefrecord in android

Tags: android

I would really appreciate your help. Been searching for the solution for about a week. Nowhere on the internet can I find the solution. I am reading a basic NdefRecord - text. The NdefRecord contains a number. I have no problem reading the record, but I cant covert it to an into an integer, it just doesn't convert. Here is how I get the record;

public String getTextFromNdefRecord(NdefRecord ndefRecord){//get the information
          String tagContent = null;

```
    try{
        byte[] payload = ndefRecord.getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128)==0)? "UTF-8":"UTF-16";
        int languageSize = payload[0] & 0063;
        tagContent = new String(payload, languageSize+1, payload.length-languageSize-1, textEncoding);
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        Log.e("getTextFromNdefRecord",e.getMessage());
}return tagContent;
}
```

And here is how I read it and display. I also try to convert it to a string without any prevail;

private void readTextMessage( NdefMessage ndefMessage ) {
        NdefRecord[] ndefRecords = ndefMessage.getRecords();

```
    if(ndefRecords!=null&&ndefRecords.length>0){
        NdefRecord ndefRecord = ndefRecords[0];
        String tagContent = getTextFromNdefRecord(ndefRecord);
        int num = Integer.parseInt(tagContent);
        txtTagContent.setText(tagContent);
        //Toast.makeText(this,tagContent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No NDEF message found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any guidance...

Comment: What is the value of tagContent which you passed in this :int num = Integer.parseInt(tagContent);

Comment: Its a double digit number i.e. 50. Nothing fancy

Comment: I am sorry if this is so trivial  - still cant find good guidance on the web

Comment: Treid this - still no success:   if (isNfcIntent(intent)) {              NdefMessage[] message;     Parcelable[] rawMsg = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES); message = new NdefMessage[rawMsg.length]; for (int i = 0; i < rawMsg.length; i++) {
message[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsg[i]; } if (message!=null) {String results = " "; byte[] payload = message[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();  for (int b =3; b < payload.length; b++) { results += (char) payload[b];  tagContent.setText(results); TextView num = (TextView) indViewById(R.id.txtTagContent);